# Find who created the folder and who it was last modified by with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script that retrieves folders/files that are older than 7 years (wherever I choose) and puts the report into an Excel file.  Here is my code:

```
$Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
$Daysback = "-2555"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($DaysBack)
Get-ChildItem  -Recurse $Path | Select Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, DirectoryName | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Export-Csv -Path C:\OlderThanSevenYears2.csv
```

Trying to add 2 fields: Who created the Windows folder AND who last modified file/folder.

How is this done?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can use `Get-ACL` to find the owner. Not sure about editor.

Comment: A directory has an _owner_ (retrievable from `Get-Acl` as Jacob Colvin notes), but that might be different from the principal that _created_ the directory. The `LastWriteTime` property provides the last modification date for the directory.

Comment: You cannot see this in Windows Explorer, so I'd guess this cannot be done.

Comment: The owner of a folder is not necessarily who created it. You cannot identify creator or user who made the last change in retrospect. You need to have [file and folder auditing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771475.aspx) enabled beforehand, so you can extract the information from the audit logs.

Comment: Everybody had excellent answers, Ansgar Wiechers thank you for the most useful comment!  Exactly the answer I was looking for.  This answers my question.